# Doing processing on a text file uploaded

Tags: javascript, html

I want to upload a text file on a webpage, read it, and then in javascript do some computation on the content of the file, e.g by calling a function called:

```
  do_calculation().
```

Here is the code I have so far. But it is not complete as I don't know how to read the content of the file from: function do_calculation().

html code:

```
  <tr>
  <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
  <td><input type="file" id="pubkey"></td>
  <output id="result" />
  <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


function loadFileAsText(){
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("pubkey").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
       var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      document.getElementById("result").value = textFromFileLoaded;
  };

   fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");


  }

   function do_calculation(){

   }

   </script>
```

Moreover, I'd like to know how I can work on two uploaded files.

Comment: so in the onload function call the function and pass in the content....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call your `do_calculation()` function in your `filereader.onload` fucntion and give it the parameter of the text. Then you can do whatever you want with the text at that point within your `do_calulation()` function

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxmngk0r/

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you also give me a hint on how to  upload two files and work on both?

Comment: No problem glad I could help. If I solved the answer to this question, please mark as the accepted answer and ask a new question about how to upload two files, I'll be glad to help on that problem as well. It just needs to be a separate question so this question can be resolved.

Comment: Ah ok. Well what is the question for the two file upload problem you're having?

Comment: Assume i upload two files. I want to read the content of both and then I call again do_calculation() function to do some computation- for instance   one file is for public key and the other one is for signature and do_calculation() wants to verify the signature using the public key

Comment: or even simpler, one file contains value 1 and the other file contains value 2, the do_calculation function wants to do 1+2.

Comment: So you want to upload 2 files and more or less merge them together?

Comment: yes to some extent... I want to run a computation on content on both, e.g. add or multiply their values together.

Comment: Do you care if I add more buttons? Or does it have to be the only 2 buttons you already have? I would probably have to add another upload file button in order to get 2 files, but can keep the same `do_calculations` button

Comment: @Ay. I've done basically the basic idea of uploading 2 files and combining them together within this jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/po8gnhqy/. I don't know if this is exacly what you're looking for but it should give you a good starting point to get what you need. Hopefully this helps. You have to click the "Load Selected file" button to get the text before clicking the "Combine" button by the way.